# Flutter draggable ListItem - No Material Widget found

Tags: flutter

In the absence of any cookbook examples for a drag and drop ListView, I'm trying to create my own but when trying to drag a row I get the error: No Material widget found. I've tried wrapping the ListTiles, in containers but always seem to get the same error.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Basic List';

    var tile1 = new ListTile(
      leading: new Icon(Icons.photo),
      title: new Text('Row 1'),
    );

    var tile2 = new ListTile(
      leading: new Icon(Icons.photo),
      title: new Text('Row 2'),
    );

    var tile3 = new ListTile(
      leading: new Icon(Icons.photo),
      title: new Text('Row 3'),
    );

    return new MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text(title),
        ),
        body: new ListView(
            children: [
              new Draggable(child: tile1, feedback: tile1),
              new Draggable(child: tile2, feedback: tile2),
              new Draggable(child: tile3, feedback: tile3),
            ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try wrapping a [`Material`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Material-class.html) class.

Comment: Thanks, that's cleared that error but introduced another one:

`The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded.
When a row is in a parent that does not provide a finite width constraint, for example if it is in a
horizontal scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the horizontal axis. Setting a
flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining
space in the horizontal direction.`

Answer (score 5):

Maybe, not the best solution, but it suits for me

```
Draggable(
  axis: Axis.vertical,
  maxSimultaneousDrags: 1,
  child: tile,
  childWhenDragging: Opacity(
    opacity: 0.5,
    child: tile,
  ),
  feedback: Material(
    child: ConstrainedBox(
      constraints:
          BoxConstraints(maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width),
      child: tile,
    ),
    elevation: 4.0,
  ),
```

I've wrapped tile in `ConstrainedBox` with width from screensize.